# `std::enable_if` SFINAE custom type via template parameter?

Tags: list, c++11, templates, std, enable-if

**First question**: let's say that I have a custom `struct` like this one:

```
struct Var {};   

struct is_var_type: std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<Var, typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::value> {};
```

After this, I want to have some custom type via a template parameter SFINAE using `std::enable_if`, however I couldn't figure it out. I could only do this:

```
template<typename T> 
void variant(T a)
{ 
    if (is_var_type<Var>::value){
        std::cout << " " << true;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << " " << false;  
    }
}
```

I want to make something like this one, but `std::is_integral` has already been defined. How is a custom one made?

```
template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = nullptr> // I couldn't figure out how to make custom integral_constant via template parameter 
T foo3(T t) // note, function signature is unmodified
{
    return t; //so this type should be an int, but I want to make sure that this type T is is_var_type struct, is this possible?
}
```

**Second question**: is this way possible if we add some container type like this?

```
struct Var {};
struct ListVar: public std::list<Var>
struct is_var_type: std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<ListVar, typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::value> {};
```

– but I got an even more confusing compile time error, something like cannot deduce multiple type in `gcc 4.9`.

Comment: Shouldn't `is_var_type` be a template?

Comment: I edited again my question, to make this more clear.

Comment: `struct Var:{};` - Why the colon ? This does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make `is_var_type` a template alias wrapping `std::is_same`. A solution could look like this.

```
#include <type_traits> // for std::decay
#include <iostream>

struct Var {};

// define is_var_type
template<class T>
using is_var_type = std::is_same<Var, typename std::decay<T>::type >;

// function that works for Var
template<class T
       , typename std::enable_if<is_var_type<T>::value>::type* = nullptr
       >
T foo3(T t)
{
   std::cout << " T is type Var " << std::endl;
   return t;
}

// function that works for int
template<class T
       , typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,int>::value>::type* = nullptr
       >
T foo3(T t)
{
   std::cout << " T is type int " << std::endl;
   return t;
}

int main()
{
   Var v;
   foo3(v); // calls foo3 for type Var

   int i;
   foo3(i); // calls foo3 for type int
   return 0;
}
```

You can also define `is_var_type` using `std::integral_constant` like you did in your example (you were missing `template<class T>` before your definition):

```
template<class T>
struct is_var_type:std::integral_constant<bool,std::is_same<Var,typename std::decay<T>::type>::value > 
{
};
```

---

EDIT:

For a container of `Var` it is the same story as above, now we just check whether `T` is of type `ListVar`:

```
// define structure that is a list of Var
struct ListVar : public std::list<Var>
{
};

// struct that checks whether T is a ListVar
template<class T>
struct is_list_of_var_type : std::integral_constant<bool,std::is_same<ListVar, typename  std::remove_cv<T>::type>::value > {};

// function that only works for ListVar
template<class T
       , typename std::enable_if<is_list_of_var_type<T>::value>::type* = nullptr
       >
T foo3(T t)
{
   std::cout << " T is type ListVar " << std::endl;
   return t;
}

// ... some code ...
ListVar lv;
foo3(lv); // call foo3 for ListVar
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, how about my second question according to you with the same use case but with addition of container type, any idea?